# Python threading: "sys._current_frames()" vs "threading.enumerate()"

Tags: python, multithreading, celery

I have a program which forks a number of subprocesses (it's using Celery Workers for that matter). I'm trying to dump the stack traces of all the running threads in each process. I'm using `sys._current_frames()` to get the stack traces and `threading.enumerate()` to get the thread names.

For some reason, I noticed that, in my forked sub-processes, I have more "frames" than actual threads. Is this normal?  Are these just "leftovers" from the fork?  Is it a bug in Python?  (tested on Mac OS X, for the record)

Thanks,
Z

Answer (score 3):

This is [bug 17094](http://bugs.python.org/issue17094). It should be fixed in later Python versions.

Answer (score 1):

Well the documentation of sys._current_frames explains something slightly
Firstly

> This function should be used for internal and specialized purposes only.

So its not really something you should be poking. And the key answer comes from threading.enumerate documentation

> The list includes daemonic threads, dummy thread objects created by current_thread(), and the main thread.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and indeed read the documentation. The fact is that sys._current_frames is mentioned as a tool for debugging. I've seen many pieces of code floating around that use it, and what I found simply breaks most of them.